# Populating a table with data from file based on condition. Correct approach?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I've briefly encountered SQL in the past, however this is the first time I'm trying anything this advanced. The overall goal of the database is to provide step-by-step instructions to assemble a physical part in a factory. The catch, however, is that different variants of different parts can be assembled.

I have a basic data architecture (described below), however I'm not too sure how robust it is. The general idea is that a part is detected and identified via RFID and the required instructions are 'loaded' into the instruction table.

I have a table named 'Assembly', which contains the partID, type and variant. This has a one-to-many relationship with a table called 'Instruction', which contains fields such as scheduledStart, actualStart, status and ID. 'Assembly' also has a 1-1 relationship with a WorkStation table (parts can move between work stations for different stages of assembly), which contains a 'filePathToWorkInstructions' field that links to a file with the work instructions for each part and variant for that station.

I'm not expecting a full step-by-step answer, nor do I really want one (I quite like the challenge). I'd just quite like to know if I'm heading in the correct direction or if there is a better way to approach the problem.

Comment: Does anything prevent you from storing the files in the database, like extreme size, frequent changes from other applications that can only handle files or are they different for each created instance?
Otherwise I would store them into the database directly, which makes it easier to query for missing files before the workstation wants to load it and it's missing...

Comment: @neurotic-d I can't see any issues with storing the files in the database. Would it be OK practice for the C# program running on the PC connected to the RFID system to pull the file, parse it, and write the relevant information back to the database?

Comment: So there are changes to the file involved? Then I would probably stay at the filePathToWorkInstructions-approach to keep the overhead of file storage small (depending on DBMS).
I assumed you had a set of constant instruction files for each workstation/part/variant tuple and just needed to provide the workstation with the right one, which would have kept everything in the DBMS's reach

Comment: @neurotic-d They are static, however the process times for each is likely to change, so I'll stick with the filePathToWorkInstructions method. Thanks.